# UITapGesture to drag view but limiting the bounds of which it can be dragged

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently have 2 circles. One big circle and one little circle. The little circle has a tap gesture recognizer that allows it to be dragged by the user. I would like the little circle's center to go no further than the big circle's radius. I have 4 auto layout constraints on the inner circle. 1 for fixed width, 1 for fixed height, 1 for distance from center for x, and 1 for distance from center for y. Here is how I am going about this:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat x = recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x;
        CGFloat y = recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y;
        CGPoint desiredPoint = CGPointMake(x, y);

        //check if point the user is trying to get to is outside the radius of the outer circle
        //if it is, set the center of the inner circle to the right position at the distance of the radius and with the same angle
        if ([self distanceBetweenStartPoint:self.outerCircleView.center endPoint:desiredPoint] > self.outerCircleRadius) {
            CGFloat angle = [self angleBetweenStartPoint:self.outerCircleView.center endPoint:actualPosition];
            desiredPoint = [self findPointFromRadius:self.outerCircleRadius startPoint:self.outerCircleView.center angle:angle];
        }

        //adjust the constraints to move the inner circle
        self.innerCircleCenterXConstraint.constant += actualPosition.x - recognizer.view.center.x;
        self.innerCircleCenterYConstraint.constant += actualPosition.y - recognizer.view.center.y;

        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) inView:self.view];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)distanceBetweenStartPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint {
    CGFloat xDif = endPoint.x - startPoint.x;
    CGFloat yDif = endPoint.y - startPoint.y;
    //pythagorean theorem
    return sqrt((xDif * xDif) + (yDif * yDif));
}

- (CGPoint)findPointFromRadius:(CGFloat)radius startPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint angle:(CGFloat)angle {
    CGFloat x = radius * cos(angle) + startPoint.x;
    CGFloat y = radius * sin(angle) + startPoint.y;

    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}

- (CGFloat)angleBetweenStartPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint {
    CGPoint originPoint = CGPointMake(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y);
    return atan2f(originPoint.y, originPoint.x);
}
```

This works almost perfectly. The problem is I try to find the percentage that the user moved towards the outside of the circle. So I use the distanceBetweenStartPoint(center of outer circle) endPoint(center of inner circle) method and divide that by the radius of the outer circle. This should give me a value of 1 when the circle has been dragged as far to one side as it can go. Unfortunately I am getting values like 0.9994324 or 1.000923. What could be causing this? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You need to google about floating-point calculation precision

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. It seems like NSDecimalNumber would be the best choice?